# Как грамотно построить предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Как более грамотно построить фразу:
"Занял первое место на районных соревнованиях ДОСААФ по стрельбе из малокалиберной винтовки среди всех возрастов" или "занял первое место на районных всевозрастных соревнованиях ДОСААФ по стрельбе из малокалиберной винтовки"? Важно подчеркнуть, что в соревновании участвовали и юноши и взрослые, без разделения на возрастные группы.

Comment: Разнобоя — среди всех возрастов / всевозрастные, быть не может. Надо уточнить название. Если же этих слов в названии нет, то можно назвать первое место абсолютным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Соревнования проводятся не "среди возрастов", а среди участников (людей разного возраста).

Если в рамках соревнования распределение мест проводилось только *одним* способом (без учёта возраста), то  "возраста" характеризуют само **соревнование** (состав допускаемых к нему участников):

> Занял первое место на районных соревнованиях ДОСААФ по стрельбе из
> малокалиберной винтовки, *проводившихся для участников всех возрастов*.

Если же это одна из нескольких номинаций (например,  места внутри возрастных групп тоже определялись), то "возраста" относятся к **способу определения места**:

> Занял *первое место среди участников всех возрастов* на районных
> соревнованиях ДОСААФ по стрельбе из малокалиберной винтовки.